# Understanding difference between functions

Tags: javascript

I understand what the code below does:

```
var x = myFunction(3, 4)

function myFunction (a, b) {
    return a * b;
}

console.log(x);
```

It will create a function called myFunction, call it with 3 and 4 and return 12.

But I don't understand what the difference between the above code and the code below.

```
var myFunction = function (a, b) {
    return a * b;
};

var x = myFunction(3, 4)
console.log(x);
```

If we can write code like the first one, why do we need to write code like the second one?

Thanks.

Comment: you don't have to write it in the second form in fact